# Why it skips the if block

Tags: java, android

Apology for another newbie question. I have this block of code in my MainActivity should check the users and returns an appropriate activity based on the if else statement. Problem is that it skips the if block and I can't figure out why. All I know is that the getID function works fine on other classes. Thank you for reading this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    UserFunctions userFunctions;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        UserFunctions fn = new UserFunctions();
        String id = fn.getID(getApplicationContext());

        if("100".equals(id)){

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminActivity.class);           
            startActivity(in);          
            finish();

        }else{

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserActivity.class);                        
            startActivity(in);      
            finish();

        }
    }
}
```

UserFunction Class

```
/* Get user ID from DatabaseHandler */
    public String getID(Context context) {
        String id = "";
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        Cursor cursor = db.getUserID();

        if(cursor != null) {
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                id = cursor.getString(0);
            }
        } else {
            id = "";
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return id;
    }
```

DatabaseHandler Class

```
/* Get user ID from the database */
    public Cursor getUserID() {
        String qry = "SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();     
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(qry, null);     
        return cursor;

    }
```

Comment: Which if block? Is id ever 100 and is cursor ever null?

Comment: I recommend you try to step through the code with a debugger - eclipse IDE has a great built-in debugger, if you get the package that includes Android stuffs...

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys inside of the MainActivity class

Comment: @PoweRoy should I change to int? Does it really matter?

Comment: @nana does the else execute when the if skipped ??or are you getting an exception of some sort ?

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR yes. it executes the else statement fine so I'm not getting any error. It's just skipping the if block for some reason.

Comment: so when it goes into the `else` block what is the value of `id`?

Comment: @nana, so its obvious, your id is never equal to 100. just to test hard code your id as 100 and test it, it should execute the if

Comment: @dave.c every other ID except the "100".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getID() method always returns the ID of the last user in the database.  This user is not id=="100" since your if statement is evaluating to false.

In getUserID, you select all records in the login table.  Then:

```
if(cursor != null) {
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        id = cursor.getString(0);
    }
} else {
    id = "";
}
```

if there are any users, this will return the ID of the last one, if there are no users, it will return "".

Comment: Simon, thank you for your advice! Your comment does make sense for me. Could you please then show me or refer me how I can check the ID so the users don't have to login every time application opens?

Comment: This is Android.  There is only one user.

Comment: thanks again. But could you advice me on how I can work around kindly?

Comment: I'm sorry, but since there is only one user, I have no idea what you're trying to do :)  What do you mean "login"?

Comment: Basically trying to check the user roles and returns different activity. I'm using userID instead of the roles because it's a small app.

Comment: so you need the id for the current user. If there are more than one users in the database you will need some WHERE clause to select the id of the current user. I can't understand where the user is authenticated... I mean you select all ids from the database but there is no other criteria - you still don't know which one you need to check.

Comment: Nana.  I suggest that you start a new question and think about how people who have no idea what you are doing can answer the question. If the question does not contain all of the detail, you will simply get more questions. e.g. what do you mean by "roles"?  How do the users login?  How do you know which user is logged in.  All of these must be in the detail of your question.

Comment: ok.I will start a new question regarding this. Thank you much!